# Can I make the indent commands take an additional count that doesn't affect the motion?

Tags: key-bindings, indentation, count

Let's say I'd like to indent the current line 4 times. (Not 4 spaces, 4 indent commands). As far as I can tell, the shortest way to do this is

```
>>...
```

(Indent once, repeat three times) This seems really inefficient to me. I'd rather do something like this:

```
4>>
```

But instead of repeatedly indenting the current line, this indents the next *4 lines 1 time*. In my mind, this is a total waste, because if the count *before* the operator was "indent level", and the count after is for a repeated motion, this doesn't lose any ability. If I wanted to indent the next four lines one time, I could just do

```
>4>
```

or even

```
>3j
```

If the first count were to work this way, you could even do a command like this:

```
2>4>
```

And this would mean "Two times, indent the following four lines". Instead it means "One time, indent eight lines".

Can I configure vim to behave this way?

Comment: see also: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3702581/4748017

Answer (score 6):

You can do:

```
:>>>>
```

to shift the current line 4 times.

So you could write a custom normal mode mapping that shifts the current line `{count}` times:

```
nnoremap <expr> <F5> ":\<C-u>" . repeat(">", v:count1) . "\<CR>"
nnoremap <expr> <F6> ":\<C-u>" . repeat("<", v:count1) . "\<CR>"
```

and its visual mode counterpart:

```
xnoremap <expr> <F5> ":" . repeat(">", v:count1) . "\<CR>"
xnoremap <expr> <F6> ":" . repeat("<", v:count1) . "\<CR>"
```

Mixing `{count}` and `{range}` may be a bit more complicated.

Answer (score 4):

alternate using visual mode:

```
V4>
```

Or just

```
v4>
```

as mentioned in the SO thread [How do I indent a single line multiple times in vi or vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3702581/how-do-i-indent-a-single-line-multiple-times-in-vi-or-vim)

For multiple lines, for example - current line and 3 lines down, indent twice:

```
v3j2>
```